# wanted the font size of a textLabel to be scaled according to the text on the view

Tags: iphone, ipad, fonts, uitextfield

i am developing a app where i get data from xml and i parse them and use it in application.I get a text to be placed in a textField along with font style and size from xml.This xml is generated on a system which runs on windows. 
**situation:**
i have a situation where i am getting the font size as 8 from xml and after parsing  and displaying the text in the textField the text size looks very small almost like ants.Where as the text with the same font and same size looks neat and clear on desktop.

Is there any scaling mechanism which enables me to scale the text size to a bigger size which makes it visible easily without me increasing the size of the font .

TNQ

Answer (score 1):

I think font size = 8 is actually quite small. Perhaps you could scale the value that you receive from the server by a scale factor (say 1.5 or 2).

```
NSUInteger SCALE_FACTOR = 2;
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:SCALE_FACTOR * xmlValue]; //xmlValue is the value you get from the server
```

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: ya i too thought the same but could not figure out how to scale it.can u plz guide me in that?

Comment: hi akshay that is a great solution.what if i need the scaling only when the font size is small.is there any difference the way the fonts look in the desktop and ipad.

Comment: The font appearance would depend on the device's resolution, which would be different for desktops & iDevices. If you want to scale only if it is small, you can define a good enough font size (say 12), below which you will not multiply by the scale factor. Also, you could define different scale factors for different size buckets, say 2 for 2-8, 1.5 for 9-12, etc.

Comment: is it the only best way or is there any property or support provided by ios.i think there should be one

Comment: If it is a UILabel with a single line of text, you can set minimumFontSize. That's the last thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the size (as a CGSize) that a string of a certain font will be using NSString's drawing methods (sizeWithFont: and variations). Use this together with the size of your label to determine the correct font size to use.